# Apache2 fails because of www-browser

Tags: server, apache2, firefox

Running an Ubuntu LAMP server for months suddenly no longer works.
Apachectl status gives an error 113: www-browser : not found.
Maybe you need to install a package providing www-browser or you need to adjust APACHE_LYNX variable in apache2.envvars.

My default browser is the current Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04.

The APACHE_LYNX variable has always been commented out in envvars.
Uncommenting it and even changing -dump to --dump has no effect.
What am I missing?

Comment: What is the output of `update-alternatives --display x-www-browser` ?

Comment: x-www-browser - auto mode   link best version is /usr/bin/firefox   link x-www-browser is /usr/bin/x-www-browser/usr/bin/firefox - priority 40

Answer (score 6):

If something is checking your Apache status with a script or other command-line method, you may need a text-based browser to be installed. The `w3m` package is a decent tool for this. Here's how you can install it:

0. Update `apt` if it's not already up to date:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
1. Install `w3m`:

   ```
   sudo apt install w3m
   ```
2. Restart Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

This should resolve the issue

Comment: No script is being used, but unable to locate package w3m